# Almacenar caracteres desde un archivo txt a un arreglo en C

Tags: array, c, txt, caracteres

Necesito tomar unos nombres desde un archivo txt y ponerlos en un arreglo para trabajarlos.
Tengo un código que lee el documento txt y imprime los datos, los traté de poner en un arreglo, pero el problema es que muestra como letras, pero cuando quiero acceder a ellos, son enteros y de hecho me tira números si trato de imprimir una posición en específico:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LONGITUD_MAXIMA_CADENA 1000 // Cuántos bytes leer en cada iteración
    
int main(){
    char const s[] = "\n\t";
    char *token;
    char arreglo[LONGITUD_MAXIMA_CADENA];
    int longitud;
    FILE *archivo =fopen("di.txt", "r") ;
    char bufer[LONGITUD_MAXIMA_CADENA]; // Aquí vamos a ir almacenando cada línea
            
    while (fgets(bufer, LONGITUD_MAXIMA_CADENA, archivo))
    {
        longitud = strlen(bufer);
                
        token = strtok(bufer, s);
        // La imprimimos, pero realmente podríamos hacer cualquier otra cosa
        while( token != NULL) 
        {
            printf( "\n%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, s);
            for(int i = 0; i<=longitud; i++){
                arreglo[i] = bufer[i];
                putchar(arreglo[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En el archivo di.txt tengo estos nombre así:

> Carlos
> Maria
> Marta
> Jeremias

Debería tomar uno por uno y ponerlos en un arreglo al menos esa es la idea.

Comment: strtok modifica el bufer haz la copia antes de llamar a strtok...o mejor no uses el bufer usa el token

Answer (score -1):

La funcion strtok viene en string.h y toma dos argumentos; el primero indica la cadena que vamos a dividir (es importante saber que esta cadena será modificada, así que si queremos que se mantenga intacta debemos copiarla a otra variable) y el segundo indica una lista de delimitadores.

Un ejemplo de como concatenar token en una matriz de caracteres:

```
int n=0;        
while (fgets(bufer, LONGITUD_MAXIMA_CADENA, archivo))
{           
    token = strtok(bufer, s);
    // leemos los token de cada fila o buffer
    while( token != NULL) 
    {   
        longitud=strlen(token);
        printf( "\n%i:%s\n",longitud, token);
       //guardamos el token en la matriz, vector o pila de caracteres
        for(int i = 0; i<=longitud; i++,n++) arreglo[n] = token[i];
           
        arreglo[n-1]=' ';arreglo[n]=0;//separamos por espacio y finalizamos la cadena
        //mostramos todo lo procesado
        for(int i = 0; i<strlen(arreglo); i++) putchar(arreglo[i]);
        
         token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
}
```

Nota que el tamaño del buffer de entrada no debería ser igual al tamaño de la pila donde guardamos los tokens para que no se nos vaya de rango(**stack overflow**).

Una ejemplo mas sofisticado de como funciona un compilador:
Llámanos a nuestro código token.c para autocompilarse.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LONGITUD_MAXIMA 10000
#define LONGITUD_MAXIMA_FICHERO 100000 
    
int main(){
    char const s[] = " \n\t";
    char *token;
    char *arreglo[LONGITUD_MAXIMA];
    int longitud;

    FILE *archivo =fopen("token.c", "r") ;
    char bufer[LONGITUD_MAXIMA_FICHERO]; // Aquí vamos a ir almacenando todo el fichero
    int n=0;
    int contador=0;        
    while (fgets(bufer+contador, LONGITUD_MAXIMA_FICHERO-contador, archivo))
    {           
        token = strtok(bufer+contador, s);
        // leemos los token de cada fila o buffer
        while( token != NULL) 
        {   
            longitud=strlen(token);
            printf( "\n%i:%s",longitud, token);
           //guardamos el token en la matriz, vector o pila de caracteres
           
            arreglo[n++] = token;
            contador=token-bufer+(longitud+1);          

            
             token = strtok(NULL, s);
        }
    }
    //mostramos todo lo procesado
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) printf( "\n%i:%s",i, arreglo[i]);
}
```

Nota que los token se almacenan en el propio buffer de entrada el cual vamos avanzando gracias a la variable contador:

```
contador=token-bufer+(longitud+1);
```

Y que tenemos un vector de punteros que apunta a cada token dentro del bufer

```
arreglo[n++] = token;
```

Entonces, podemos entender el extraño comportamiento que esta haciendo *strtok*

1. Es una función que tiene memoria para las siguientes
   iteraciones(guarda un puntero al bufer y/o al final del ultimo token
   tratado).
2. Recorre el buffer ignorando los caracteres en 's' o los
   delimitadores
3. Al encontrar el primer token o carácter distinto al delimitador se guarda el puntero para luego devolverlo.
4. Sobrescribe un \0 o fin de cadena al final del token, modificando
   el contenido del bufer.